Excluding multiple file types from .asar packing
i am curently trying to mod skype to make a similar program to "betterdiscord" but for skype.
the way it works is because of its framework "electron" and unpacking the asar file in the program directory and re-packing it again with the modified code.
the issue im having is that. the file doubles in size after packing.
which is because of the .node and .dll files and a folder (images/tray) getting packed within the .asar instead of being spat into another directory app.asar.unpacked.
From my knowledge i can exclude files using :
asar pack unpacked app.asar --unpack "*.node"
it excludes the node files from the packed asar file, but no matter what i do i cant seem to find any way to exclude multiple file types and directories(.node, .dll and the images/tray folder).
sorry if its a stupid question, im pretty new to this kinda stuff.
Thank you in advance!!!
